# Taylor series coefficient representation around 0

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \text{B}_R(0) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic, with power series $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k z^k$ (where $B_R(0)$ is the open disc centered at 0 of radius $R$). Show that for $0 < r < R$ and $k \geq 1$, the coefficient $c_k$ is given by:

$c_k = \frac{1}{\pi i} \oint_{\partial \text{B}_r(0)} \frac{\text{Re}(f(w))}{w^{k+1}} \, dw$

I know that the formula for $c_k$ is given by the Cauchy's integral formula:
$c_k=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\partial \text{B}_r(0)} \frac{f(w)}{w^{k+1}} \, dw$

So I have rewritten $\frac{1}{\pi i} \oint_{\partial \text{B}_r(0)} \frac{\text{Re}(f(w))}{w^{k+1}} \, dw=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\partial \text{B}_r(0)} \frac{f(w)+\overline{f(w)}}{w^{k+1}} \, dw$.

But now I am stuck.

Comment: The formula for the coefficients is missng a $k!$. Use $\overline w=|w|^2/w$ to calculate the integral $\int \frac{\overline{f(w)}}{w^{k+1}}dw=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\overline c_n \int \frac{\overline w^n}{w^{k+1}}dw$.

Comment: Oh, now I see thank you. But i don't think that there is a $k!$ missing.

Comment: You are right about the $k!$.